# How can I have a div at 73px and an iframe at 100% on the same page?

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

This should be easy, but I've spent a while trying to figure this out... I have a div that is 73px in height. I also have an Iframe that is suppose to stretch to the rest of the page but it overflows and I have two scroll bars (Iframe, and page). How can I have the div above the Iframe and have the Iframe in 100% height? I've also tried a negative margin and padding and that hasn't done anything.

Trying to get rid of the page scroll bar when using 100% and top: 73, but you can see the code for yourself.

Comment: I personally use jquery to calculate the remaining amount and assign a height to iframe, just a thought... you might also want to consider a 95% at all times, its nasty but it covers 95% of situations :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this an interesting problem, so I've spent some time debugging the design on your page.

Now for me, the textarea always stretch exactly to the bottom of the page, not farther, and the page scrollbar does not appear.

Here are the modifications (I hope you did not change your code or stylesheets too much while I was debugging):

1.) - The "container" div:

Using `bottom: 0` together with `position: absolute` ensures that the div stretch to the end of the page. Using `height: 100%` would cause the div to overflow! Using `overflow: hidden` does not allow the page scrollbar to show up.

```
<div class="container" style="position: absolute; top: 73px; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; left: 50%; margin-left: -475px;">
```

2.) - The left pane ("span-12" div):

```
<div class="span-12" style="float: left; padding-top: 17px; width: 470px">
```

3.) - The right pane ("span-12 last" div):

You can use the same trick as with the "container"
 div: absolute positioning and use of the top, right and bottom css properties.

```
 <div class="span-12 last" id="friend_pane" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0">
```

4.) - And the iframe:

```
<iframe src="/friend/shell.php" frameBorder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
```

EDIT - To make it center-aligned, I added "left: 50%; left-margin: -475px;" in the style of the "container" div. This tricks belongs to @clairesuzy, I didn't find it myself.

Comment: This worked great except my container and two divs are now aligned to the left side of the page... any ideas? Ive updated my answer with a picture of the problem

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realized that you wanted the two divs be center-aligned. You could set a margin (e.g. 20%) so that they are not so far on the left, but that's not the same thing as a scalable center alignment so I am going to look for another solution.

Comment: Now I know how to make it center-aligned, thanks to @clairesuzy, I have updated my post. There was also a small syntax fault that caused the container div to have no top padding. Now everything should work fine.

Comment: @Luc1245 good job :) and I see you removed the unnecessary float (`#friend_pane`) too - when an element is positioned it won't respect float anyway so the original float was harmless - However without `height: 100%` on the `friend_pane div` IE7 will not stretch the iframe.. and if you use it you don't need both the top and bottom 0's (it depends on if @Pete Allport needs IE7 support though ;))- PS: you may want to correct that `left-margin` typo to `margin-left`

Comment: @clairesuzy Yes, I think your solution is probably better than mine... PS: Thanks for reading my post and telling me about the typo!

Comment: Thanks you two you have really helped me out!

Comment: @Pete you're welcome.. @Luc1245 it wasn't who had the 'better solution' it was who helped the most, and the right person got picked :)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/HZTTp/:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
html, 
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    padding: 0 !important;
    padding: 30px 0 0;
}
#top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: gray;
}
html 
> 
body 
#bot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
object {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top"></div>
        <div id="bot">
            <object data="foo"></object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think you may want to add some explanation on what it does and why it works.

Comment: If someone asks, I’ll probably clarify, but no point typing everything I know about the code in the interim.

Comment: Heh - I think @icktoofay was asking! Remember, this is a reference site - the answers should be useful to future readers, not just get the original asker out of trouble once...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wrapper `div` on the `iframe` to specify where you want it's sides to be (`top:73px; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;`) with the help of `position:absolute`.

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="head"></div>
<div id="main">
    <iframe src="http://i.reddit.com/"></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#head { height:73px; background:#c33; }
#main { top:73px; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; position:absolute; }
#main iframe { border:0; width:100%; height:100%; display:block; }
```

**Demo:** [**jsfiddle.net/fErZY**](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/fErZY/2/)

Comment: If you use the wrapper as described here then it might leak slightly off the bottom of the page, but the body { overflow:hidden } takes care of that for you.

Comment: @Steve: Right you are, I've removed `overflow:hidden` and added `display:block` on the `iframe` for a more robust answer.

Comment: This is great. Very robust, and will work just about everywhere. There is a fix you'll need to apply for IE6 if you care about that browser: it doesn't support both top+bottom or left+right absolute position at the same time. The fix is detailed here: www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/

Answer (score 2):

A bit tricky.. and most solutions work OK for the main part but IE7 doesn't like when a `iframe` is set to 100%  tall without it's parent having an explicit height (in px, not percent) - so my solution is to absolutely position the `container` so you get the 73px top and 0 bottom co-ordinate you need - then it should be as simple as setting the `#friend_pane` div to 100% height, and then subsequently the `iframe` to 100%.. but that's the bit IE7 doesn't like.. so adding `position: absolute; right: 0;` also to the `friend_pane` div, along with the 100% height - then makes IE7 apply the 100% height to the iframe too.

There is leakage (small?), if that's what you've been referring to in your comments, that is to do with the iframes natural box model, but I found setting a negative bottom margin `-4px` on the iframe counteracts that

So with your code; remove all inline styles from `.container` `#friend_pane` and the iframe `#friendpane_area`

and add these styles:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 73px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -475px;
    background: #cff; /* for testing only */
}

#friend_pane {
   position: absolute; 
   right: 0;
   height: 100%; 
   background: #fcf; /* for testing only */
}

#friend_pane iframe {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   width: 470px; 
   height: 100%; 
   margin-bottom: -4px;
}
```

Here's a demo of this with your page code:

### [JSBin HERE](http://jsbin.com/icoji5/)

**Note:** `overflow:hidden;` on the `#friend_pane div` **instead of** the negative 4px margin on the `iframe` will also cure the "leakage"

---

and to keep some general code in the answer.. a simplified demo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>FriendsConnect | My dashboard</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

body {
  background-color: #4DA2CA; 
  margin: 0px; 
  padding: 0px;
  }

#mainbar {
   background-image: url('http://friendsconnect.org/bar_fade.png'); 
   background-repeat: repeat-x; 
   background-color: #494949; 
   padding-top: 6px;
   height: 67px;
} 

#infobox_left {
   color: #444444; 
   margin-bottom: 15px; 
   padding: 15px; 
   background-image: url('http://friendsconnect.org/grp2.png');  
   background-color: #F2F2F2; 
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   float: left;
   width: 440px;
}

#com-status {
  border: solid 1px; 
  border-color: #3B7D99; 
  background-color: #4794B7;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 440px;
  }
  

.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 950px;
    top: 73px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -475px;
    background: #cff; /* for testing only */
}

#friend_pane {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; 
   right: 0;
   height: 100%; 
   background: #fcf; /* for testing only */
}

#friend_pane iframe {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   width: 470px; 
   height: 100%; 
   margin-bottom: -4px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="left" id="mainbar">Main bar</div>

<div class="container">
    <div style="padding-top: 17px;" class="span-12">
      <div id="infobox_left">
        <font color="#000000">Welcome TEST, what's up?<br/></font>
        SOCIAL POINTS&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#000000">0 Points</font><br/>
        ACCOUNT STATUS&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#2C8231">No Problems Found</font><br/>
        CONNECTBOX&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#000000">0 New Messages</font>
      </div>

      <div id="com-status">
         <strong>Pete Allport commented on your status</strong><br/>Pete Allport Commented: Yeah bro thats beastt...&nbsp;
         <div style="float: right;"><button>Close</button></div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div id="friend_pane">
      <iframe id="friendpane_area" src="http://google.com" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

which you can see:

### [JSBin Here](http://jsbin.com/edele4)

Comment: Wow, you obtain a center alignment by combining a relative left (50%) and an absolute left margin (-475px). I'll remember that trick... Please can you explain how you calculate this last value?

Comment: @Luc1245 it's half the container width which is 950px in OP's page code and my second example.. left 50% moves the whole container so it's left edge is in the middle of the body.. negative half the  width moves it back left by half it's own width ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `iframe` in a `div` and set the div's `position:fixed` with `top:73px` then `right`, `bottom`, and `left` set to 0 so the div fills remaining space below your 73px header.  Once your wrapper is set you can specify height and width to 100% for your iframe.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/KTwxb/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <iframe id="frame" src="http://www.supercalifragilisticexpialidocious.com/"></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;}

#header {width:100%;height:73px;}

#wrapper {position:fixed;top:73px;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;}
#frame {width:100%;height:100%;border:0;}
```

Comment: leaking meaning the iframe is off the page or iframe page is requiring scrolling?  Also you may try `position:absolute` as an alternative to `fixed`, not sure that will fix it though

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Only way I was able to hide the scroll bar was to  set the iframe's html overflow property to hidden.
http://jsfiddle.net/nERqu/

HTML:

```
<div class="top">
    <p>div text</p>
</div>
<iframe class="iframeBottom" src="http://www.google.com">
</iframe>
```

CSS:

```
.iframeBottom {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    scrolling: no;
}
.top {
    height: 73px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like iframe is being treated as an absolutely positioned element whether or not you actually specify that in the css.  If its container is absolutely positioned, it should be able to fill the container using width:100% and height:100%.

In other words, if my theory is correct, the iframe isn't sizing "correctly" because it is searching for a positioned (i.e. relative, absolute, just not static) parent element.  It needs to figure out how to adjust its size and the closest abs pos element is the browser viewing area itself.  100% height of the screen would normally fill the screen height, but the iframe is positioned down 73px, thus making it overflow by 73px.

Play with this a bit, it should be a nice step in the right direction:

```
<div style="position:absolute; width: 515px; top:73px; bottom:0px; right:0px;">
    <iframe id="friendpane_area" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height: 100%;" src="./FriendsConnect   My dashboard_files/shell.htm" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```